# Captcha: is it enough?

Tags: security, captcha

I'm implementing [re-captcha](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php?hl=fr&csw=1).
And I'm just wondering if I have to spend some time implementing [CSRF](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) or if a captcha eliminates the need for the [CSRF protection](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure how a CAPTCHA would provide any guard against CSRF. CSRF occurs when a user authenticates with a secure site, and then visits a malicious site that then submits requests to the secure site via forms, images, AJAX that leverage that authenticated connection.

CAPTCHA only ensures that someone is a human being, typically for ensuring that a commenter or a new registrant is a person, and not a bot. I would never rely on CAPTCHAs for any sort of security, as bots are now better than humans at reading some of them.

Comment: Captchas *can* prevent CSRF attacks as the victim would require to solve the Captcha to agree with the attacker’s forged request. However, I would rather implement a transparent CSRF protection as solving a Captcha for each request (with side effects) would be quite annoying to the user.

Comment: Note Gumbo's qualification. If you use a CAPTCHA for this, you will need the user to enter the CAPTCHA each and every time, a usability nightmare. There are other solutions that adequately solve the issue without impacting the user experience.

Comment: For each form the user has to fill, he will be forced to fill another CAPTCHA to avoid bot automation.